# Grant somebody access to something or Grant access to something for somebody

Tags: phrases, expressions

Often I have to request access to specified resource for specified person. Is there any error in any of these forms and what is better to use?

Grant somebody access to something
Grant access to something for somebody

Comment: Please spell out smth and smb, as I did in my edit.  A question here is a formal communication and words should be spelled out, especially in the title.

Comment: They are both acceptable.  I like the first because the “for somebody” at the end of the second is just slightly more ambiguous than I’d like, although in context nobody would likeky bat an eye

Comment: @Jim why not add this as an answer?

Comment: As Jim noted, they are both acceptable, but I would like to add that the 'canonical' example of such duality concerns the verb 'provide' - e.g., "I provided the guests with chairs." and "I provided chairs to the guests." Here, the second one, using 'to' instead of 'for', lacks the ambiguity complained of by Jim. (This duality sort of reminds me of the 2 forms of De Morgan's Law.)

Answer (score -2):

Grant is fine, as are your examples.  You can also use:

- Allow.  I'll allow you to x, y, and z...
- Permit.  You're permitted to x.  You have my permission to x.
- Bestow.  I'm bestowing the ability to do x unto you.